# angular/typescript serialize data

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular application I need to turn json/raw data into typescript objects. The data is a combination of primitive properties and related objects that also need to be converted.

e.g. json/raw data

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Smith',
    email: 'jsmith@test.com'
    status: {
        id: 100,
        name: 'Active'
    }
}
```

e.g. call to api and map data to objects

```
public getList(): Observable<{ data: T[], meta?: any }> {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${environment.api_url}/items`)
                          .pipe(
                            map((response: any) => { return {...response, data: response.data.map(item => new Item(item))};
                          }));
}
```

and in the constructor of my Item class.

```
constructor(props: any = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
    this.status = props.status ? new Status(props.status) : undefined;
}
```

I also have all of my class properties strongly typed e.g.

```
public id: number;
public name: string;
public email: string;
public status: Status
```

This all seems to work well, my only question is related to my use of `Object.assign(this, props);`, is there any potential issues with how I have done this? The main objective of this is so that I don't have to write every property assignment into the constructor e.g. `this.name = props.name`. Is Object.assign the correct function to use?

Comment: I've done this a bunch of times, and am curious to see if there's a better way.  So far, as long as the data I get is exactly what I expect I haven't had any issues.

Comment: Are you just needing to type the response of your service call? or do you actually need to create a new class instance for every object returned?

Comment: I need to create a new class as I want to create other method e.g. create an address() method that combines street, city, state etc... There are a lots of other examples as well.

Comment: A slightly different approach would be to pass the JSON from the service call to a factory method. In this factory method, you could assign the address values you need to the object returned, which can still be a plain object of type T, instead of having to create a class instance for each. But, it just depends on your individual use cases. Neither is really "better"